# ¿Canvas y keylistener?

Tags: java, canvas

como podría hacer para, borrar lo que tengo en el canvas y re-dibujarlo usando keylistener, o re-posicionar; tengo pensado que al momento de recibir la acción de la tecla se debe ejecutar el cambio de posición pero no conozco que puedo usar para lograrlo.

Intente inicializando los valores del circulo pero tuve la misma duda, por ultimo, el manejo con teclado tiene alguna diferencia que con las "Flechas" o es la misma practica.

Gracias por su atención.

```
public class Proyecto extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

    
    public Proyecto(){
        addKeyListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500,500);
    }
    
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        //Circulo Grande
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
        
        //Circulo interno
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(150, 150, 50, 50);
        
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='a'){}
    }

    
}
```